# Modifiers and Symbols Used in Netsuite Results Formulas

Tags: html, sql, netsuite

I'm essentially looking for a list of some type of modifying symbols to use primarily when setting up results in NetSuite saved searches.

Example: CASE WHEN {altname}  'test' THEN ''||{altname}||'' END

`CASE WHEN {altname} x 'test' THEN '<font color="#006400">'||{altname}||'</font>' END`

I placed x primarily where I'm looking for options. I'm aware of the standard >, <, and = but I'm unable to locate any other sources for potential modifiers.

Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19188_01/doc/B15917/sqopr.htm Section 2.4 gives a list of comparison operators available.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

" docs.oracle.com/cd/B19188_01/doc/B15917/sqopr.htm Section 2.4 gives a list of comparison operators available. – Acroyear "

Thank you!